# Revolution Slider - Image Quality is bad but i uploaded in Full hd

Tags: wordpress

no idea why but since today Revolution slider doesn't work right for me... or I do something wrong.
The pictures I upload and set as Backgroud are in Full HD and on the PC super sharp... But as soon as I upload the whole thing in wordpress and put it on a slider and look at it live on the website the picture looks super pixelated...
I don't know what to do.

I've been spending, like, three hours fixing something... no luck. I have tried to use the image in png and jpg. More dpi (which is totally stupid because 72 is enough)... I just don't know what to do.

This is on Slider: http://prntscr.com/on6fpp
This is the "normal" quality: http://prntscr.com/on6fyi

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using Elementor Page builder to fix the layout. Unless RevSlider is called via a shortcode. If so, replace the shortcode by Elementor's Slider option.

I stopped using RevSlider due to high amounts of unexpected errors.

Elementor is super easy.

Try it out.